# Extracting an IP address from a particular string in Lua

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I want to extract a particular value from a string . This is my string

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 666 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.19.55
```

How can i extract `192.168.19.55` ip address from this string using string.match in lua ?

I done with `local ip = s:match("--to-destination (%d+.%d+.%d+.%d+)"))` but i didn't get the value 192.168.19.55 . I am getting empty value .

Any mistake in this ? Any suggestions ?

Comment: You need to use `%-` to escape `-`, which is a magic character in Lua patterns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
local s = "iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp --dport 666 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.19.55"
ip = s:match("%-%-to%-destination (%d+%.%d+%.%d+%.%d+)")
print(ip)
-- 192.168.19.55
```

See the [online Lua demo](https://ideone.com/9rVoAR).

Note that `-` is a lazy quantifier in Lua patterns, and thus must be escaped. Also, a `.` matches any char, so you need to escape it, too, to match a literal dot.

See more at [Lua patterns Web page](https://www.lua.org/pil/20.2.html).

Comment: Note that if you are sure it is always IP that comes from `destination`, you may also use [`s:match("%-%-to%-destination ([%d.]+)")`](https://ideone.com/pTzGrq). A `.` inside `[...]` does not have to be escaped, and `[%d.]+` matches one or more digits or dots.

Answer (score 3):

This also works:

```
ip = s:match("destination%s+(%S+)")
```

It extracts the next word after `destination`, a word being a run of nonwhitespace characters.

Comment: Yes, it would work for IPv6 too.  But probably it would be better to restrict number of available characters (for example, `()-"` should not be allowed)